# Arduino Uno prescaler, not measuring what I expected

Tags: arduino, timer, interrupts, arduino-uno

I'm using the following code to set a pin high or low (each cycle.) I measure that pin with a logic analyzer.

I use an Arduino Uno with 16MHz frequency. I set a timer interrupt with a prescaler of 64, according to the [datasheet.](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf)

Now, when I measure the pin I indeed see highs and lows but the odd part is, the distance between two edges is ~8us, I expected 4us.

When I set the prescaler to clk_io/8 rather than clk_io/16 I get 3us which I do not understand either.

What am I missing here? Which critical concept am I overlooking or did I configure something incorrectly?

[image]

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

bool test = false;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  
  //    set pin PORTD_2 to output
  DDRD |= 1 << 2;

  //  TIMER 1
  //  Atmega328p (arduino nano)
  TCCR1A = 0x0000;
  //  CLK = 16MHz, we will have a bit change every 4us (250kHz) -> prescaler = 16/0,25=64
  //  set prescaler to 64 (TCCR1A_cs2=0_cs1=1_cs0=1)
  //  also set the mode to CTC (1 << 3)
  TCCR1B = 0x0001 | (1 << 3) | (1 << 1); //timer prescale factor 64
  //TCCR1B = 0X0000 | (1 << 3) | (1 << 1); //timer prescale factor 8

  //  Set Output Compare Register A for timer 1 to 1 = 0x0001
  OCR1A = 0x0000 | 0x0001;
  

  TIMSK1 = 0x0000 | (1 << 1);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}


ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect){
  if(test) {
    PORTD &= ~(1 << 2);
  }else {
    PORTD |= 1 << 2;
  }
  test = !test;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you don't enable the waveform generation (magic number 1<<3)?

Comment: honestly, i would not know myself but it made sense to enable by reading the datasheet. Maybe you can ask the question to @carl below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you set `TCCR1A = 0`  and `TCCR1B = 0000 1011`  you are using clear-timer-on-compare mode (`WGM[3:0] = 0100`) and a prescaler of 64 (`CS[2:0] = 011)`. Since `OCIE1A` is set in `TIMSK1` when the interrupt flag for timer1 is set the interrupt routine `TIMER1_COMPA_vect` will be issued.

In your code you have set \$OCR1A=1\$ which will issue an interrupt every

$$T_{dur}=\frac{1+OCR1A}{f_{clk}/N_{prescaler}} = \frac{1+1}{16\text{MHz}/64} = 8\mu\text{s}$$

You want \$T_{dur} = 4\mu\text{s}\$ so the compare value stored in `OCR1A` with a prescaler of 64 has to be

$$OCR1A = \frac{f_{clk} \cdot T_{dur}}{N_{prescaler}}-1 = \frac{16\text{MHz} \cdot 4\mu\text{s}}{64}-1=0 $$

If you instead use a prescaler of 8, the compare value should be \$OCR1A = 7\$ which I would recommend doing due to the better time resolution and to avoid any unexpected outputs.

By the way, since you are altering the `test` variable in your ISR you should make it volatile to make sure the compiler doesn't create a copy of the variable and changes that instead. This is easy to do, just declare `test` like this:

```
volatile bool test = false;
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me like your code is dividing *again* by 2, by inverting PORTD_2 at each interrupt. That would explain why the frequency is half what you expected. If instead you set *and* reset PORTD_2 at each interrupt, you'd get the right frequency, albeit with an extremely low duty cycle.

You may also be falling victim to slow code. I'm guessing that the interrupt service routine isn't always completing before the next interrupt arrives. This would cause serious jitter at your output, which, depending on your scope's triggering, may appear to be consistent when it's actually all over the place. Or, at best, skipping beats.

You could speed things up a lot with an XOR operator to directly flip a single bit, instead of reading and writing "test" each time, and performing a an "if" comparison:

```
PORTD = PORTD ^ (1 << 2);
```

Comment: Very great addition, specially in my given example. Unfortunately in the final application it is not a 'toggle' operation so in particular this cannot be used. However, I will look where i can apply these features, thanks!

Comment: @Mart in general you want to keep ISRs quite short—consider flipping a toggle in the ISR and using the value of that toggle to determine if you should enter a specific state in the mail loop

Answer (score 0):

You are counting two counts with the timer so it does not generate overflows every prescaled tick but every two prescaled ticks.